# How to push a List<> to a subdocument in mongodb?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to push a List to the subdocument of a document.
If I insert just a single object as BsonDocument it works as shown below:

```
BsonDocument subdoc = new BsonDocument {
                 { "_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId()},
                 {"name", "Mr Bob"}
                };

                var query = Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId("1234.."));
                var upd = Update.Push("members", subdoc); <-works
                groups.Update(query, upd);
```

But I need to push a List. I am getting this exception:

```
"WriteStartArray cannot be called when State is: Initial"
```

This is the code that is failing:

```
List<BsonDocument> newMembers = new List<BsonDocument>();
BsonDocument subdoc  = new BsonDocument {
                     { "_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId()},
                     {"name", "Mr Bob"}
                    };
newMembers.Add(subdoc );
subdoc = new BsonDocument {
                     { "_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId()},
                     {"name", "Mr Tom"}
                    };                
newMembers.Add(subdoc);

var query = Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(id));
var upd = Update.Push("members", newMembers.ToBsonDocument()); <- EXCEPTION
groups.Update(query, upd);
```

After the insertion, I would see:

```
groups:
{
  _id:1,
  members:[
   {   
      _id:1,
      name: "Mr Bob"
   },
   {   
      _id:1,
      name: "Mr Tom"
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since newMembers already List of `BsonDocument` you no need convert it to BsonDocument again.

If you want push more than one document to the a nested array you need to use [$pushAll](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pushAll):

```
var upd = Update.PushAll("members", newMembers.ToArray());
```

In case if you will need push List items of some class you need convert each item to BsonDocument:

Lets say that newMembers is List of Member class, then if you need push List to a nested array you should do something like this:

```
var upd = Update.PushAll("members", newMembers.Select(x=> x.ToBsonDocument()).ToArray());
```

**Update:**

1. To make subdocument not unique for same user names you can create algoritm that will generate same id from same user names. Most simple algoritm can just replace all spaces with underscore and make ToLower().
2. Another way load embedd array with `$slice` and check uniqueness of each subdocument.

Comment: Is there a way to check for duplicate? One of the new entry might have name="Mr Bob" which already exists in the subdocument. Is there a way to check for this like in $addToSet?

Comment: @Projapati: There is no way to do it with `push`. Why not just use $addToSet?

Comment: works like a charm. I had to add .ToBsonDocument() as w/o it, it gives syntax error. I think the key is ToArray(). Thanks Andrew.

Comment: AddToSetEach() seems inserting duplicates since each member has different _id (ObjectId.GenerateNewId) even the name is same. This makes each subdocument unique. Anyway to push only those from the List<> which has different values in the name field?